# How to set Yaru icon theme as fall back in 20.04

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, 20.04

I hate the folder colours in 20.04. So I used an icon theme of my own with very few customisations ( folder, trash can etc). I have set the `index. theme` file as

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=Jadu
Comment=Jadu icon theme
Inherits=breeze,gnome,hicolor,yaru

Example=folder

FollowsColorScheme=true

DesktopDefault=48
DesktopSizes=16,22,24,32,48,64
ToolbarDefault=22
ToolbarSizes=16,22,24,32,48
MainToolbarDefault=22
MainToolbarSizes=16,22,24,32,48
SmallDefault=16
SmallSizes=16,22,24,32,48
PanelDefault=48
PanelSizes=16,22,24,32,48,64
DialogDefault=48
DialogSizes=16,22,24,32,48,64

# Directory list
Directories=8x8/emblems,16x16/actions,
```

I was hoping that other than my customisations, the icon theme will fetch from the default icon theme which is Yaru. Currently, my customisations are working, but for icons which I do not have custom variants, it fetches from some other theme ( Adwaita ?), which looks odd.

I wanted to ask that how can I define in `index.theme` file to fetch unavailable icons from Yaru icon theme which is OS default.

Comment: Try changing `Inherits=breeze,gnome,hicolor,yaru` to have `yaru` first or just `yaru`?

Comment: Tried first, last and yaru alone. It is using Adwaita, I think. Which is Gnome default. Thanks.